# This C program outputs garbage

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char a='x'; 
    printf("%c %d",a);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> x 134513696

What is 134513696?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Garbage. This is due to a programming error: 
You put only one parameter on the stack (a), but printf takes 2 values from the stack, because of the two percent signs.

If you intended to have both outputs, the character and its ordinal value, you should have written `printf("%c %d", a, a);`

Comment: if %d did not point to a integer.instead if it points to char or string what happens.

Comment: @bobby: You can't predict this: Printf takes whatever it finds on the stack. If you use %s the application might crash, but this is a different story.

Comment: #include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
 printf("%u %s/n",&"hello",&"hello");
return 0;
}

Comment: can explain me above program in comment im trying to analyze it.but confused.pls edit it.i dont know how to.thnx

Comment: related question.. are the elements actually removed from the stack in a C function call, so that an incorrect number of arguments could result in a potentially disastrous situation?

Comment: @Pete: Calling convention of printf is cdecl which means: Caller pushes arguments and pops them after the call returned. This is necessary for vararg functions. So: No this is not a problem.

Comment: What is interesting is that the program prints garbage instead of crashing... Honestly, I would expect it to crash

Answer (score 2):

If the number of format specifiers in `printf()` is greater than the number of arguments passed the behaviour is **undefined**.

For example :

```
printf("%d %d %d", 1, 2); // UB
printf("%f %d %d"); // UB
```

However if the arguments are greater in number(than the format specifiers) the extra ones are just evaluated and ignored.

For example :

```
printf("%d" ,1,2); //fine. Prints 1
```

Comment: .. I think you would like to edit and correct your response. Especially this line : `printf("%d %d", 1, 2); // UB`.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you enter into a contract with a mafia boss to buy a shipment of goods for $1000. Then instead you only hand over $500, and that night you go home to find a dead kitten in your bed. What did you expect?! C is the mafia boss and you you broke your contract with him. Be glad it was just a useless number on your terminal and not your computer blowing up.

Comment: thnx .u explained it very well.

Answer (score 0):

`printf` uses a variable argument list. It cannot check if the number of arguments in your format string (in your case 2 `"%c %d"`) are equivanlent to the number of arguments inside the [va_list](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdarg/va_list/) (you have just one), so it will grab some undefined value. The compiler will not check for you, if the format string is properly formated.